# Вывод данных из нескольких таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Подскажите как вывести данные из нескольких таблиц в один dataGridView? У меня есть две таблицы "korzina" и "auth". Из таблицы "korzina" нужно вывести столбцы id_product, name, price, id_client а из таблицы "auth" столбец tel. Подскажите как это сделать

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Напишите правильный запрос, который вернет то что вам надо и выводите его результаты

Comment: Я не знаю как написать многотабличный запрос у меня есть только однотабличный вот такой  using (MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("Select id_product, name, price, id_client from korzina ", con))

Comment: Ну тогда у вас вопрос не по C#, а по SQL, приведите в вопросе структуру таблиц (метки я поправил). Либо, для начала, изучите sql-инструкцию `JOIN`